# Rails application doesn't work with apache2 and passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger, ruby-on-rails-2

Can't make my rails 2.3.5 application work correctly with apache2. In apache errors log i get the following:

```
/usr/lib/phusion_passenger/passenger-spawn-server:53:in `require': no such file to load -- phusion_passenger/utils (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/phusion_passenger/passenger-spawn-server:53
[ pid=9437 file=ext/apache2/Hooks.cpp:727 time=2012-04-02 20:04:49.923 ]:
Unexpected error in mod_passenger: Cannot spawn application '/home/user/projects/pname/trunk': The spawn server has exited unexpectedly.
  Backtrace:
     (empty)
```

I've tried to reinstall passenger, apache but that didn't help. What should i do to start the application? How can i get phusion-passenger to work?

Comment: Are you using libapache2-mod-passenger or are you using the passenger gem and passenger-install-apache2-module?

Answer (score 0):

from the error, I suppose you haven't installed some gems/components.

Follow the official document step by step, and you will make it done:  http://www.modrails.com/install.html

p.s.  from this post: http://markmail.org/message/pyikfcnn3nczhoiz, did you installed 2 versions of ruby?

> It was a problem of having both ruby and ruby enterprise edition. I
>   removed the former, installed phusion passenger again and it worked.

Comment: Are you using libapache2-mod-passenger or are you using the passenger gem and passenger-install-apache2-module?