# Redmine and backlog no such file to load -- phusion_passenger/utils (LoadError)

Tags: passenger, redmine, backlog

I tried to install redmine with backlog plugin. I followed this tutorial: https://github.com/backlogs/redmine_backlogs/wiki/Installation-of-Backlogs-in-Redmine-2.0

And now I have apache error:

```
/usr/lib/phusion_passenger/passenger-spawn-server:53:in `require': no such file to load -- phusion_passenger/utils (LoadError) 
        from /usr/lib/phusion_passenger/passenger-spawn-server:53:in `<main>'
[ pid=4064 file=ext/apache2/Hooks.cpp:725 time=2012-09-16 23:23:45.726 ]: 
  Unexpected error in mod_passenger: Cannot spawn application '/var/www/redmine': The spawn server has exited unexpectedly. 
  Backtrace: 
     in 'virtual boost::shared_ptr<Passenger::Application::Session> Passenger::ApplicationPoolServer::Client::get(const Passenger::PoolOptions&)' (ApplicationPoolServer.h:471) 
     in 'int Hooks::handleRequest(request_rec*)' (Hooks.cpp:521)
```

This is my virtual host config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName redmine.my.domain 
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/redmine/public" 

  <Directory "/var/www/redmine/public/">
    RailsBaseURI /redmine 
    PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on 
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My /etc/apache2/mods-available/passenger.conf

```
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
  PassengerRoot /usr 
  PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby 
  PassengerDefaultUser www-data 
</IfModule>
```

More:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -> /etc/alternatives/ruby 
/etc/alternatives/ruby -> /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1

ruby -v
ruby 1.9.1p378 (2010-01-10 revision 26273) [x86_64-linux]
```

Any idea?

Comment: Are you using libapache2-mod-passenger or are you using the passenger gem and passenger-install-apache2-module? Did you get it working?

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at the hints from this question: [Rails application doesn't work with apache2 and passenger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980733/rails-application-doesnt-work-with-apache2-and-passenger) ? (it looks like the same type of error). One person had several versions of Ruby installed which was causing problems.

Hope it'll help.